# React CSSTransitionGroup - Unexpected Ref Object provided for div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

so I have recently started learning React.

My goal is, to have a container with newest messages,...

Whenever there is a new message, by clicking on it, the message should dissapear, and the containers height should shrink.

I've tried CSSTransitionGroups, but I still get the following errors:

```
[Error] Warning: Unexpected ref object provided for div. Use either a ref-setter function or React.createRef().
   in div (at App.js:52)
   in MessagesContainer (at App.js:32)
   in div (at App.js:21)
   in App (at src/index.js:8)
   in StrictMode (at src/index.js:7)
   printWarning (0.chunk.js:26512)
   error (0.chunk.js:26484)
   commitAttachRef (0.chunk.js:46321)
   commitLayoutEffects (0.chunk.js:49087)
   callCallback (0.chunk.js:26612)
   dispatchEvent
   invokeGuardedCallbackDev (0.chunk.js:26661)
   invokeGuardedCallback (0.chunk.js:26714)
   commitRootImpl (0.chunk.js:48824)
   commitRootImpl
   unstable_runWithPriority (0.chunk.js:59056)
   commitRoot (0.chunk.js:48666)
   finishSyncRender (0.chunk.js:48083)
   performSyncWorkOnRoot (0.chunk.js:48069)
   scheduleUpdateOnFiber (0.chunk.js:47465)
   updateContainer (0.chunk.js:50614)
   (anonymous function) (0.chunk.js:50997)
   unbatchedUpdates (0.chunk.js:48183)
   legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (0.chunk.js:50996)
   ./src/index.js (main.chunk.js:1405)
   __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:785)
   fn (bundle.js:151)
   (anonymous function) (main.chunk.js:1432)
   __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:785)
   checkDeferredModules (bundle.js:46)
   webpackJsonpCallback (bundle.js:33)
   Global Code (main.chunk.js:1)
[Error] Warning: Unexpected ref object provided for div. Use either a ref-setter function or React.createRef().
   in div (at App.js:52)
   in MessagesContainer (at App.js:32)
   in div (at App.js:21)
   in App (at src/index.js:8)
   in StrictMode (at src/index.js:7)
   printWarning (0.chunk.js:26512)
   error (0.chunk.js:26484)
   commitAttachRef (0.chunk.js:46321)
   commitLayoutEffects (0.chunk.js:49087)
   callCallback (0.chunk.js:26612)
   dispatchEvent
   invokeGuardedCallbackDev (0.chunk.js:26661)
   invokeGuardedCallback (0.chunk.js:26714)
   commitRootImpl (0.chunk.js:48824)
   commitRootImpl
   unstable_runWithPriority (0.chunk.js:59056)
   commitRoot (0.chunk.js:48666)
   finishSyncRender (0.chunk.js:48083)
   performSyncWorkOnRoot (0.chunk.js:48069)
   performSyncWorkOnRoot
   (anonymous function) (0.chunk.js:37553)
   unstable_runWithPriority (0.chunk.js:59056)
   flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (0.chunk.js:37548)
   flushSyncCallbackQueue (0.chunk.js:37536)
   flushPassiveEffectsImpl (0.chunk.js:49158)
   unstable_runWithPriority (0.chunk.js:59056)
   (anonymous function) (0.chunk.js:48978)
   workLoop (0.chunk.js:59000)
   flushWork (0.chunk.js:58956)
   performWorkUntilDeadline (0.chunk.js:58560)
[Error] Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here:
   in div (created by Message)
   in Message (at App.js:81)
   in Transition (created by CSSTransition)
   in CSSTransition (at App.js:74)
   in DismissableMessage (at App.js:61)
   in div (at App.js:52)
   in MessagesContainer (at App.js:32)
   in div (at App.js:21)
   in App (at src/index.js:8)
   in StrictMode (at src/index.js:7)
   printWarning (0.chunk.js:26512)
   error (0.chunk.js:26484)
   findHostInstanceWithWarning (0.chunk.js:50552)
   performExit (0.chunk.js:55172:115)
   updateStatus (0.chunk.js:55119)
   componentDidUpdate (0.chunk.js:55081)
   commitLifeCycles (0.chunk.js:46130)
   commitLayoutEffects (0.chunk.js:49082)
   callCallback (0.chunk.js:26612)
   dispatchEvent
   invokeGuardedCallbackDev (0.chunk.js:26661)
   invokeGuardedCallback (0.chunk.js:26714)
   commitRootImpl (0.chunk.js:48824)
   commitRootImpl
   unstable_runWithPriority (0.chunk.js:59056)
   commitRoot (0.chunk.js:48666)
   finishSyncRender (0.chunk.js:48083)
   performSyncWorkOnRoot (0.chunk.js:48069)
   performSyncWorkOnRoot
   (anonymous function) (0.chunk.js:37553)
   unstable_runWithPriority (0.chunk.js:59056)
   flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (0.chunk.js:37548)
   flushSyncCallbackQueue (0.chunk.js:37536)
   discreteUpdates$1 (0.chunk.js:48172)
   discreteUpdates (0.chunk.js:27234)
   dispatchDiscreteEvent (0.chunk.js:30633)
   dispatchDiscreteEvent
[Error] Warning: Unexpected ref object provided for div. Use either a ref-setter function or React.createRef().
   in div (at App.js:52)
   in MessagesContainer (at App.js:32)
   in div (at App.js:21)
   in App (at src/index.js:8)
   in StrictMode (at src/index.js:7)
   printWarning (0.chunk.js:26512)
   error (0.chunk.js:26484)
   commitAttachRef (0.chunk.js:46321)
   commitLayoutEffects (0.chunk.js:49087)
   callCallback (0.chunk.js:26612)
   dispatchEvent
   invokeGuardedCallbackDev (0.chunk.js:26661)
   invokeGuardedCallback (0.chunk.js:26714)
   commitRootImpl (0.chunk.js:48824)
   commitRootImpl
   unstable_runWithPriority (0.chunk.js:59056)
   commitRoot (0.chunk.js:48666)
   finishSyncRender (0.chunk.js:48083)
   performSyncWorkOnRoot (0.chunk.js:48069)
   performSyncWorkOnRoot
   (anonymous function) (0.chunk.js:37553)
   unstable_runWithPriority (0.chunk.js:59056)
   flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (0.chunk.js:37548)
   flushSyncCallbackQueue (0.chunk.js:37536)
   discreteUpdates$1 (0.chunk.js:48172)
   discreteUpdates (0.chunk.js:27234)
   dispatchDiscreteEvent (0.chunk.js:30633)
   dispatchDiscreteEvent
```

So my code looks like this:
In the App Component, I am calling

```
<MessagesContainer></MessagesContainer>
```

```
function MessagesContainer() {
  const [menuHeight, setMenuHeight] = useState(null);
  const dropdownRef = React.createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    setMenuHeight(dropdownRef.current?.firstChild.offsetHeight);
  }, []);

  function calcHeight(el) {
    const height = el.offsetHeight;
    setMenuHeight(height);
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ height: menuHeight }} ref={{dropdownRef}} className="messages-container">
      <DismissableMessage
        header="Welcome back!"
        content="This is a special notification which you can`t dismiss."
      ></DismissableMessage>
      <DismissableMessage
        header="Welcome back!"
        content="This is a special notification which you can`t dismiss."
      ></DismissableMessage>
      <DismissableMessage
        header="Welcome back!"
        content="This is a special notification which you can`t dismiss."
      ></DismissableMessage>
    </div>
  );

  function DismissableMessage(props) {
    const [visible, dismissMessage] = useState(true);

    

    return (
      <CSSTransition
        in={visible}
        unmountOnExit
        timeout={500}
        className="message-dismiss"
        onExit={calcHeight}
      >
        <Message
          onClick={() => dismissMessage(!visible)}
          header={props.header}
          content={props.content}
        />
      </CSSTransition>
    );
  }
}
```

Please tell me if you need anything, thanks in advance.